# export of a groupby element/list with a condition IF to an excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, if-statement, save

I would like to check a "worksheet" if it contains more than e.g. 250 entries if it does I would create a new excel-sheet and save it in a new file.

For example:

```
Leading-Zip:   Adresses that contains the Leading-Zip:
--------------------------

74                  400
73                  200   
72                   50
```

I used this command to get the number of entries I want to group:

```
worksheet['Zip-code-region'].value_counts()
```

Which way do I have to choose to make that?
Do i have to create a list? or could I use a command with a for-loop?

Try a Update:
I am importing a excelfile:

```
xel = pd.read_excel(r'C:test.xlsx', sheet_name = None)
```

than i select a sheet:

```
worksheet = xel[ws]
```

now I add a new column 'leading-zip' slicing the ZIP code:

```
worksheet['leading-zip']=worksheet['zip-code'].astype(str).str[:2].astype(int)
```

from that 'leading-zip' I want to iterate each 'leading-zip' - count the adresses contained in it and if they are more than 250 I want to create a new excel file.

Comment: please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also check [how to make good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: which version of pandas you have? `pd.__version__` ? if `0.24` check with `worksheet[worksheet.Zip-code-region.isin(worksheet.groupby('Zip-code-region')['Zip-code-region'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>250].droplevel(0).index)]`

Comment: I installed the 0.24.1 one

Comment: hi anky, that worked - thanks. never in my life i would have come to this conclusion. now how do i write the selected dresses in a excel-file? i thought of using the leading-zip to add it in the file-name. like: i have more than 500 adresses in the leading-zip: 74 -> filename: zip-74.xlsx  --- and another problem: it can be various of leading-zip's with over 500 adresses.

Comment: You already have the selection, now just export it to excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `value_counts` results that are above the threshold and then loop over their indexes, saving the respective subsets from the original DataFrame as separate Excel sheets:

```
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'zip': np.random.randint(10, 100, 1000)})

z = df['zip'].value_counts()

threshold = 15

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in z[z >= threshold].index:
    df[df['zip'] == i].to_excel(writer, str(i))

# save the remaining data as worksheet 'other':
df[df['zip'].isin(z[z < threshold].index)].to_excel(writer, 'other')

writer.save()
```

Comment: No, of course you don't need to use random, I'm only generating some data here to demo how it works. Just use your own DataFrame instead

Comment: Tried it - but it doesn't work. Error: NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: You can fix it with `import numpy as np` (however I only use numpy here to generate randomized data)

Comment: `numpy` not `lumpy`?

Comment: So which error are you getting? I've added all required inputs to my code above (and tested with freshly restarted kernel), so you can try to execute the whole block

Comment: Hi, now it works! the excel ist generated. :-) thanks.

Comment: now I tried it in my program - it works - but I forgot to say that I also need the rest of adresses (all that are under 250) all in one sheet. If you might help me?

Comment: Updated my example, see the line of code below "save the remaining data as worksheet 'other'" comment